# Traits to detect if a class is compatible with std::ostream<<

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, ostream, g++4.9

I tried to implement a type_traits able to detect if a class can be used in the context of an instruction such as: `std::cout << my_class_instance;`.

My implementation tried to benefit from SFINAE to detect whether or not the function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MyClass&)` is available for the class. Unfortunately it fails under g++-4.9 which should be compatible with C++ 11. Other compilers does not complain and seem to generate the right code: g++-5+, clang++-3.3+ and also Visual Studio.

Here is the implementation I tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <class... Ts> using void_t = void;
template <class T, class = void> struct can_be_printed : std::false_type {};
template <class T> struct can_be_printed<T, void_t<decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>())>> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(!can_be_printed<std::vector<int>>::value, "vector<int> cannot be printed");
static_assert(can_be_printed<int>::value, "int can be printed");
```

Live example is available at: https://godbolt.org/g/6xFSef .
Please do not hesitate if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with how gcc interprets:

```
template <class... Ts> using void_t = void;
```

before it handled the core language issue that specifically affected that ([1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558)). Basically, gcc sees that this alias isn't affected by the template parameters and just drops in `void`. That completely defeats the purpose of `void_t` if it always succeeds, which is what is happening in this case.

You can fool it by just wrapping `void_t` in another template (as suggested in the [original paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3911)):

```
template <class... Ts> struct make_void { using type = void; };            
template <class... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
```

Here, gcc can't just drop the substituation, since there is of course hypothetically some other `make_void` specialization that isn't just `void`.